# Trouble Configuring Activities that are Opened based on EditText User Input

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am attempting to create an app in which the user navigates through a series of "menus" in order to access content.
I created the menu which appears upon opening the app

MainMenuActivity.java:

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> main_adapter;
String[] main_menu = {
        "1 INTRO",
        "2 HELP",
        "3 AROUND THE WORLD"
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu_layout);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list);
    main_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.main_list_custom_layout, R.id.main_list_item, main_menu);
    listView.setAdapter(main_adapter);
}

public void openNewActivity(View view) {
    EditText main_edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_edit_text);
    String answer = main_edit_text.getText().toString().trim();
    switch (answer) {
        case "1": {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntroActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
        case "2": {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
        case "3": {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AroundTheWorldActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
       }
        default: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and I created the menu that appears upon typing "3" (case 3) into the EditText on the first menu.

AroundTheWorldActivity.java:

```
public class AroundTheWorldActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> around_the_world_adapter;
    String[] around_the_world_menu = {
            "1 OVERVIEW",
            "2 RECEIVING"
    };
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.around_the_world_layout);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.around_the_world_list);
    around_the_world_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.around_the_world_list_custom_layout, R.id.around_the_world_list_item, around_the_world_menu);
    listView.setAdapter(around_the_world_adapter);
}

public void openNewActivity(View view) {
    EditText around_the_world_edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.around_the_world_edit_text);
    String answer = around_the_world_edit_text.getText().toString().trim();
    switch (answer) {
        case "1": {
            Intent atwintent = new Intent(this, AroundTheWorldOverviewActivity.class);
            startActivity(atwintent);
            break;
        }
        case "2": {
            Intent atwintent = new Intent(this, ReceivingActivity.class);
            startActivity(atwintent);
            break;
        }         
        default: {
            Intent atwintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AroundTheWorldActivity.class);
            startActivity(atwintent);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I configured the Activity which opens upon inputting "1" (case 1) in the secondary menu.

AroundTheWorldOverviewActivity.java:

```
    public class AroundTheWorldOverviewActivity extends Activity {

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.around_the_world_overview_layout);
        }
    }
```

around_the_world_overview_layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/atw_overview_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Around The World Overview Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am able to navigate through the second menu, but when I attempt to access the third Activity, the app stops working/crashes.

LogCat:

```
08-01 19:54:43.500 2220-2220/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search 
I/MicroDetectionWorker: Micro detection mode: [mDetectionMode: [1]].
08-01 19:54:43.502 2220-2220/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search 
I/AudioController: Using mInputStreamFactoryBuilder
08-01 19:54:43.534 2220-4313/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Starting detection.
08-01 19:54:43.540 2220-2324/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@ae6a309
08-01 19:54:43.548 1365-4316/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xacf83540 ready to run
08-01 19:54:43.562 2220-2324/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@ae6a309
08-01 19:54:43.567 2220-2324/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
08-01 19:54:43.569 2220-2324/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@ae6a309
08-01 19:54:43.573 2220-2220/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
08-01 19:54:43.588 2220-4313/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
08-01 19:54:43.588 2220-4313/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
08-01 19:54:43.590 2220-2492/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
08-01 19:54:43.591 2220-4313/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
                                                                                              com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
                                                                                               Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
                                                                                                  at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85) 
08-01 19:54:43.591 2220-4313/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: internalShutdown
08-01 19:54:43.601 2220-2220/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
08-01 19:54:43.601 2220-2220/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
08-01 19:54:43.603 2220-4312/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
08-01 19:54:43.625 2220-2234/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8140(454KB) AllocSpace objects, 7(2MB) LOS objects, 15% free, 14MB/17MB, paused 7.682ms total 89.059ms
08-01 19:54:45.634 1900-2821/com.android.phone I/OmtpVvmCarrierCfgHlpr: OmtpEvent:CONFIG_STATUS_SMS_TIME_OUT
08-01 19:54:45.641 1900-1900/com.android.phone I/RetryPolicy: discarding deferred status: configuration_state=4
08-01 19:54:45.655 1900-1900/com.android.phone D/VvmTaskScheduler: No more tasks, stopping service if no task are added in 5000 millis
08-01 19:54:45.661 1900-1900/com.android.phone D/VvmTaskScheduler: create task:com.android.phone.vvm.omtp.ActivationTask
08-01 19:54:45.662 1900-1900/com.android.phone D/RetryPolicy: retry #2 for com.android.phone.vvm.omtp.ActivationTask@6bd2e67 queued, executing in 5000
08-01 19:54:45.669 1900-1900/com.android.phone D/VvmTaskScheduler: minimal wait time:4995
08-01 19:54:45.671 1900-1900/com.android.phone D/VvmTaskScheduler: minimal wait time:4993
```

Comment: If you post crash Log maybe we can help you

Comment: That would be excellent. Unfortunately, I am relatively new to Android Studio, and I am not sure how to find the crash logs. I have Googled it several times, but I am also not familiar with android devices in general, so I am still pretty confused. Where can I find the crash log?

Comment: Bottom of the IDE there's a tab named "Android Monitor". Run your app, The crash log is available there.

Comment: Thank you, I posted it at the end of the question.

Comment: OOPS... Turns out I forgot to add an activity to the manifest. I appreciate the help! I hope this didn't waste too much of anyone's time!

Answer (score 0):

OOPS... I forgot to add an activity to the manifest file- I appreciate everyone's help, and I hope that this didn't take up too much of anyone's time!